# How to handle large values in THREE.Vector3 and get the camera right

Tags: three.js

Hei, I am having problem using lagre values in THREE.Vector3 and get the camera 
correct at the same time. I am trying to draw drilled well paths as a line.

The Y values can be 6000000 and X can be 500000 meters, these are values for
drilled wells.

The code below will show a small line, but if I increce the values in the example
nothing is shown.

So how do I deal with large values like these. I will be reading those from 
a database

```
var camera, scene, renderer, geometry, material;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 2000000);
    camera.position.z = 1200000

    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x0000ff,
    });

    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(500000, 400000, 0));
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(500000, 400000, 10000));
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(500000, 400000, 25000));
    var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
    scene.add(line);
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Comment: You can always scale your values by 100000 while drawing.